# Clock/Compass interface in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, clock

I need a clock or compass interface for a mfc-programm. I want to display wind directions with one needle, 360° scale. Is taking a clock and changing it for my use the best solution in this case.

Greez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render your own using a DC, GDI Commands and a little bit of trigonometry.  You could use something similar to this code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3475/Analog-Clock